# Using JSON to append to a list depending on ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, json

hello all I have being experiment with json and jquery and I am slighty stuck on generating lists.

I am trying to build a list from the following json file

```
{

 "svg": [

{
  "Title":"cool",
  "Description":"This is what cool should be in accordance to spec"
},
{
  "Title":"cool-act",
  "Description":"This is more in keeping with how it behaves in flash"
},
{
  "Title":"speed",
  "Description":"this is a rapid test transition time is 100ms (+-), display is 100mm"
},
{
  "Title":"desirable",
  "Description":"This is a subtle experience"
},
{
  "Title":"Maker",
  "Description":"An alternative experience speakers"
},
{
  "Title":"Hole-out",
  "Description":"colour zooms out"
}


  ],

"css" : [

{
  "Title":"test",
  "Description":"test"
}
]


}
```

I am making an ajax call to use the file and from it i wish to create a list that will eventually look like this:

```
<nav>
  <ul id="svg">
     <li>cool<li/>
     <li>cool-act<li/>
     <li>speed<li/>
     <li>desirable<li/>
     <li>Maker<li/>
     <li>Hole-out<li/>
  </ul>
  <ul id="css">
     <li>test<li/>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

and here is the function that I am using to create the menu code

```
function cannyMenu (data){


//Define categories,animation and title from JSON
$.each(data, function (category, animation) {

    // create menus based on arrays in object - svg, css etc.
    $('nav').append($('<ul>').attr('id', category));

    // create the list from each arrays object - e.g all titles within svg.
    $.each(animation, function (index, value) {

           $('ul').append($('<li>').text(value.Title));
    });

});

}
```

this issue that I am having is that while it does add the 'li' elements to each 'ul' it seems to putting the li property from my second array into the first one which is making the html output to be shown like this:

```
<nav>
  <ul id="svg">
     <li>cool<li/>
     <li>cool-act<li/>
     <li>speed<li/>
     <li>desirable<li/>
     <li>Maker<li/>
     <li>Hole-out<li/>
     <li>test<li/>/* gets duplicated */
  </ul>
  <ul id="css">
     <li>test<li/>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I need to ensure that only the properties that are related to their own array are outputted to their own lists, but i dont Have a clue on how to do this.

Any advice or help most welcomed

Thanks

Comment: You need to convert your json string to json object by using JSON.parse(data); I tried by converting it and its give result like you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you are appending the `<li>` elements you are doing so to all the `<ul>` elements in your page regardless of their id.

You want to add the value to an `<ul>` with a specific id. so change:

`$('ul').append($('<li>').text(value.Title));`

to

`$('#' + category).append($('<li>').text(value.Title));`

Hope that soves your problem.

**EDIT**

or even better, save the list element to a variable and use that:

```
  var listElement = $('<ul>').attr('id', category);
  // create menus based on arrays in object - svg, css etc.
  $('nav').append(listElement);

  // create the list from each arrays object - e.g all titles within svg.
  $.each(animation, function (index, value) {
    listElement.append($('<li>').text(value.Title));
  });
```

Comment: micnil one last question, If I was to create lists with the inclusion of anchor tags e.g <li><a href="#">.text(value.Title)<a/></li> how best would this be done in jquery

Comment: `var Title = value.Title;

            listElement.append($('<li>').prepend('<a href="#">'+ Title +'</a>'));`   just an idea what are your thoughts

Comment: Yes that works fine @W9914420. You could also take advantage of JQuerys API a bit more, eg: `var anchor = $('<a>').attr('href', '#').text(value.Title); listElement.append($('<li>').prepend(anchor));`. But either way works i guess :)

Comment: Hi micnil, your are right, i have a lot to learn and thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that this `$('ul')` will work on all ULs.  As the program loops thru the categories, its appending the animations to all ULs in the nav.  You can assign the newly created UL to a variable and avoid a second selector like this:

```
var UL = $('nav').append($('<ul>').attr('id', category));
```

and use it to append the LIs

```
UL.append($('<li>').text(value.Title));
```